# asp.net tracing without flush

Tags: .net, asp.net, trace, system.diagnostics

If I have some Trace.Write lines in my code but no listeners, will makeing those calls cause excessive memory usage/memory leak?

I'm assuming that trace.write is simply making an event call, not actually doing any data storage so based on this assumption the answer would be no, it doesnt consume a bunch of memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No memory leak, but if you turn on tracing, even if there is no listener, there is some overhead in both processor and memory. I would turn off tracing if you aren't doing anything, which can easily be done in config.

Comment: how? I don't want to remove the code then re-deploy so a config solution would be great.

Comment: I found <trace enabled="false" localOnly="true"/>